# Using PDO to connect to Access database (.accdb)

Tags: php, pdo, odbc, ms-access-2013

I am having difficulties with connecting to an Access database (specifically an Access 2013 database with an .accdb extension). Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/test/testdb.accdb";
echo $dbName."<br />";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.<br />".$dbName);
}
try {
    $db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};;Dbq=$dbName");
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />";
}
```

I have made sure that the testdb file exists in the correct folder, but when I try to create the new PDO, I am getting the following error: "could not find driver".

Now, I have gone back to my ini settings and confirmed that I have the following extensions selected:

```
php_curl
php_gd2
php_mbstring
php_mssql
php_mysql
php_mysqli
php_pdo_mssql
php_pdo_mysql
php_pdo_sqlite
```

I am using WAMP version 2.4 with PHP 5.4.16 on a Windows 7 machine.  I would appreciate any and all help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to install (if your distro has one) or compile the pdo-odbc generic driver:  http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-odbc.php